# Show time when articles were edited/created - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

Is it possible to add the time when a certain article was edited or created through the administration framework, using rails?
By adding the time, I mean when some user reads that article on the website, he can also read the last time it was edited or created.
I know I can add it manually, but I want to make it automatic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, every Rails generated model includes timestamps called `created_at` and `updated_at` which correspond to when the record was initially created (added to the DB) and last updated.

As long as your migration to create the model has the following line, then the timestamp functionality will be enabled

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      # ...

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Resources:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html